# Angular $http(...).success is not a function help rewriting the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to fix a website for a group I volunteer for.

I'm trying to update it from Angular 1.3.16 to Angular 1.6.4, but I'm getting an error message that says:

> TypeError: $http(...).success is not a function
>   at b.$scope.init (angular-custom.js:107)

The code that seems to be causing it from what I can tell by debugging it is the angular-custom.js file with the .success and .error functions:

```
$scope.init = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: $.param({ 'type' : 'getUsers' }),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.success && !angular.isUndefined(data.data) ){
                $scope.post.users = data.data;
            }else{
                $scope.messageFailure(data.message);
            }
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.messageFailure(data.message);
        });
    };
```

I have also put the files up at plunker [The 1.3.16 files at Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aOQl5MtGoNsWrCEvrBvM?p=info)

I understand that it might be the .success and .error  results, but I don't know Angular that much in how to fix it.

I'm a bit of a self-taught coder so any help would be great so I can this group up and running.

Thanks in advance for any advice.
Rod

Comment: Yes, `.success`, `.error` both were deprecated a long time ago and removed entirely in 1.6. Some relevant reading: http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-%24https-success/

Comment: Change it to `.then(function(response) { var data = response.data; ...`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I think I need to go and take the time to learn Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For angular 1.6.4 use .then and .catch to deal with the response and the error respectfully:

(note you can save some lines of code by using $http.post)

```
$scope.init = function(){
        $http.post('yourURL', $scope.yourData).
        then(function(results) {
            if(results.data.success ){
                $scope.post.users = results.data;
            }else{
                $scope.messageFailure(results.data.message);
            }
        }).
        catch(function(results) {
            //$scope.messageFailure(results.data.message);
        });
    };
```

Comment: *"next"*? Did you mean *"then"*?

Comment: The `$http` promise resolves with a `response` object, not `data, status, headers, config`

Comment: That's not true at all. For one, a promise can only resolve with a single value. Also, there is no `success` property on the response object. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage

Comment: I'm talking about this code in your answer ~ `then(function(data, status, headers, config)`. That is incorrect, the `then` callback function only has one argument; the *response* object which has properties `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config` and `statusText`

Comment: Updated, though it should be noted that the code will still run with the options status, headers and config and it should be noted that the first variable (data) can be of any name...

Comment: Thanks, AKMorris I tried the code but it didn't work, I think I'm a bit out of my depth at the moment with Angular.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to read this article
[Don't use $http's .success()](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-%24https-success/)

And

```
             $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: url,
                data: $.param({'user' : $scope.tempUser, 'type' : 'save_user' }),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).
            then(function(response) {
               your code
               excuted when post request is success
            },function(response) {

               your code
               excuted when post request is failed
            });
```

response is returned from server, you can debug to explore more deeply.

Comment: You can use .catch for errors rather than comma separating a third function - more logical to maintain the code that way.

Comment: @AKMorris I'd say that's simply personal preference

Comment: Thanks all, I'm a bit outta my depth. Have to find the time to hit the books for this old dog ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help, it seems that I really need to take some time out and learn Angular as I really don't understand how it works.

I found that the person before me got the code from [AngularJS Insert Update Delete in PHP and MySQL](http://www.vetbossel.in/angularjs-insert-update-delete-php-mysql/)

But it seems that it pops up in a few places on the net as others claiming the code as theirs. Pity about that.

Again thanks for the input but I think I can get it working on ver 1.5.11 and I'll just have to work it out at a later date.

Rod